# Can I program a raspberry Pi to stop a DC motor from turning after a specific number of rotations as counted by a Hall Sensor?

Tags: sensor

I have a project with a Gear Motor running off separate power supply via a PWM driver to control it's speed. The motor has a disc attached to the shaft with a magnet embedded in the disc that triggers a hall sensor. The hall sensor is currently connected to a display which counts the revolutions in real time. I would like to be able to set up a Raspberry Pi so that I can stop the rotations at a specific count, as well as set that count stop number using some kind of rotary encoder. This would necessitate another display as well, showing the pre-programmed revolutions before stop as set by turning the rotary encoder. Is this possible? This set up wraps electric coils, and I need to be able to program the wraps and have it stop when it reaches a specific number which varies from time to time. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I'm very new to Raspberry Pi, Linux, and coding.

To see what I'm trying to control: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2Z8fdwFkLQ

Comment: Can a Pi control a DC motor?  Yes, with some additional hardware -- perhaps not any and all motors, but you have not been more specific.  Can a Pi receive input from a hall sensor?  These come with digital and/or analog outputs; you'd need an ADC to use the latter, but in general, yes.

Comment: Would you do better to look at servos that can just go on and on and on? I would have thought the stopping accuracy of an electric motor may give you issues / extra rotations...

Comment: The video device is almost certainly using a stepper motor which is likely thee best tool for the job.  You can control the turns very accurately and accelerate/decelerate as needed. You can do what you want with a DC motor but I doubt it will be very accurate.

Comment: I'm looking at my original question, and I guess I wasn't very clear. Actual control of the motor (other than to shut it off) is not needed. All I would need the pi to do is accept some sort of count input (like 7000) from an input source (maybe a rotary encoder, or other device). Then I would need the pi to keep count of the hall sensor opening (or closing) and shut off power to the DC motor, via a relay I would imagine, when that number is reached. Because it is a geared motor it stops rapidly when power is shut off. The motor in the video is a geared DC motor with a max RPM 1000.

Answer (score 1):

The key issue you have is that you want 'real time' control.

Unfortunately, Linux is not a real time operating system and interaction between the processor and the Linux operating system may well cause timing issues so that you cannot get the precision you require.

This is a task ideally suited to an arduino and I would really recommend that over a Pi for a real time task.

Comment: The counter in that video is moving at 10-20 Hz, which should not be a problem unless you want to run tensorflow models and blockchain mining at the same time or something.